# CSS Hover image

Tags: html, css

I have an image which has and inner border with opacity set to .7 and round corners, which works great. The only problem is i need to add a hover state to image. I have tried :hover but nothing seems to work.

The border needs to go blue and with a png overlay.

HTML:

```
<div class="box" >  
<div class="imgWrap">
<img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2013/6/19/1371640593241/Morris-the-cat-009.jpg" alt="product1"  >
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    width:191px; 
    background:#FCFBDF;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
} 


img{
     width:191px;
     height:191px;
     display:block;
     border-radius:50%;

}
.imgWrap{
    position:relative;

}
.imgWrap:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    border: 10px solid rgba(248, 248, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

JS Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/52fFF/3/

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you tried to fire the hover state on the image like this :

```
img:hover{
    .. your code ...
}
```

But as there is a pseudo element over it, you can never hover the image.

The workaround is to trigger the hover state on the pseudo element like this :

```
.imgWrap:hover:after{
    border-color:blue;
    background: url('PATH TO YOUR IMAGE');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/52fFF/8/)**

Comment: Great thanks! Half way there. I also need to add a png image over top of the cat on hover

Answer (score 0):

Add hover like this.

```
.imgWrap:hover{
    width:250px;
}
```

PS : I am just adjusting the width based on hover. But you could do whatever you like in the hover.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Assuming you don't need to modify the image with the cat, web-tiki's solutions seems better.

I think you may have to use some Javascript/Jquery, as long as you can't directly trigger a mouse hover on the image (because there is some element  above).

Here is an example.

```
$(".imgWrap").hover(function(){    
    $('img').toggleClass("imgHover");
    $('.imgWrap').toggleClass("imgHover");
    $('.box').toggleClass("imgHover");
});

.imgHover{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

try this in your JSFiddle. don't forget to add Jquery lib

http://jsfiddle.net/52fFF/11/

As example i just changed the size of the Box, the Circle and the image.